# NOT LIKE not working on comparison to a column

Tags: mysql

Data is fairly large and takes few minutes to run it every time, so its taking a lot of time debugging this problem. When I run `like concat('%',T.item,'%')` on smaller data it seems to identify items properly. However, when I run it on the main DB (the code shown), it still shows many(maybe even all) of the exceptions.

EDIT:
it seems when i add NOT it stops identifying items

```
select distinct T.comment
from (select comment, source, item from data, non_informative where ticker != "O" and source != 7 and source != 6) as T
where T.comment not like concat('%',T.item,'%')
order by T.comment;
```

`commen`t and `source` are in `data`, `item` is in `non_informative`

Some items from `T.item`:

> 'Stock Analysis -', '#InsideTrades', 'IIROC Trade'

Example comment which should be removed

> '#InsideTrades #4 | MACNAB CRAIG (Director,Officer,Chief Executive
>   Officer): Filed Form 4 for $NNN (NATIONAL RETA'

Can't seem to figure out it why shows all the items

Comment: Is there a relationship (foreign/primary key) between data and non_informative? You are specifying a cartesian product.

Comment: No there is no relation between the two, non_informative has only 1 element item, which has exception values which I add as I go through data

Comment: @rodling: it's showing that comment because it does NOT match 'IIROC Trade'.  Yes, it matches '#InsideTrades', but your query doesn't care about that. Your query is finding 'IIROC Trade', which does NOT match, so the predicate returns TRUE, and the row is returned. See my answer below.

Comment: Works at a decent speed too, suggestion on how I would "tune" it? This will be used on a large and growing DB so tuning would be optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a Cartesian product between `non_informative` and `data` tables.  (Not at all clear which table the column `ticker` is from.

Understand that for a "comment" to be returned, all that is required (to satisfy the predicates in your query) is for one row to be found in `non_informative` which does not "match" the comment. There may be rows in non_informative that do match, but your query doesn't care about those. Your query is only looking for the existence of a row that does NOT match. The query is effectively saying that a "comment" will be excluded ONLY if it matches every single row in non_informative.

---

If what you want to return is the values of "comment" for which there is NO matching row in non_informative, you need a different query. (I'm going to assume that the `ticker` column is from the `data` table.)

I'm also going to exclude the corner cases of an empty string value for `item`, since that will essentially "match" every non-null value for comment.

---

## [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb679/1)

-- using a NOT EXISTS predicate:

```
 SELECT d.comment
   FROM `data` d
  WHERE d.ticker != 'O'
    AND d.source != 7
    AND d.source != 6
    AND NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM `non_informative` n
           WHERE n.item <> ''
             AND d.comment LIKE CONCAT('%',n.item,'%')
        )
  GROUP BY d.comment
  ORDER BY d.comment
```

-- or, using an anti-join:

```
 SELECT d.comment
   FROM `data` d
   LEFT
   JOIN ( SELECT n.item
            FROM `non_informative` n
           WHERE n.item <> ''
           GROUP BY n.item
        ) m
     ON d.comment LIKE CONCAT('%',m.item,'%')
  WHERE d.ticker != 'O'
    AND d.source != 7
    AND d.source != 6
    AND m.item IS NULL
  GROUP BY d.comment
  ORDER BY d.comment
```

These two statements should return an equivalent result set (but different from the resultset of your original query).  They will also likely exhibit different performance characteristics (depending on the version of MySQL, and whether the MySQL engine can transform the NOT EXISTS predicate into an anti-join operation... performance is really going to depend on what indexes are available, and generated execution plan.)

If we don't bother with the empty string corner-case, we can simplify the second statement a bit...

```
 SELECT d.comment
   FROM `data` d
   LEFT
   JOIN `non_informative` n
     ON d.comment LIKE CONCAT('%',n.item,'%')
  WHERE d.ticker != 'O'
    AND d.source != 7
    AND d.source != 6
    AND n.item IS NULL
  GROUP BY d.comment
  ORDER BY d.comment
```

Basically, for every row in the `data` table, we're checking for a "match" in the `non_informative` table. For any row where we find a "match", that row will be excluded by the "n.item IS NULL" predicate. For any row from `data` where it doesn't find a matching row in `non_informative`, the LEFT JOIN operation will generate a NULL value for the "item" column, so the row will be included in the resultset.

---

**PERFORMANCE:**

Your original query includes an inline view (aliased as `t`). MySQL is going to materialize that as an intermediate MyISAM table, before the outer query runs. And that kind of think can be a real performance killer with large tables.

But before we "tune" that statement, we really need a statement that returns a correct resultset. (There's no sense in re-writing that statement if it doesn't return the desired resultset, except as an exercise.)

Comment: How would I bypass such issue? What you said makes sense, but unfortunately my MySQL knowledge is fairly limited. And how would I optimize performace in this case? Slow speed is getting pretty bad

Comment: You are right about the speed, code works on all snippet with less 2 thousand lines but with duration of 41.5 sec. However when I run it on the main with 50k, and growing... we have some major problems with speed

Comment: 1st and 2nd code have different results and 2nd one is faster

Answer (score 1):

(old query is removed)

Try this query -

```
SELECT comment FROM data, non_informative
WHERE ticker != 'O' AND source != 7 AND source != 6
  GROUP BY comment
HAVING COUNT(IF(comment LIKE CONCAT('%', item, '%'), 1, NULL)) = 0
```

Comment: what does binary add in this case? Like function works fine on small sample without BINARY, any thoughts on why?

Comment: You can compare 'Item' to 'item'. But the the result can be 'true' or 'false'. It depends on how you need to compare these strings; and result-sets will be different in these cases.

Comment: preferbly non case sensitive, but it just doesnt work right now
i tried again, comment like concat identifies correct items. When i toss in NOT it doesnt, its mind boggling whats going on

Comment: Add to the question some `T.comment` and `T.item` values which work, and some which do not.

Comment: bingo! thanks a lot
Fairly complicated solution tho, I expected easier time comparing a column to an item with a not clause

Answer (score 0):

I do not have definite answer, but I can suggest a few possible step to investigate the case.

1. You did not show what is an error? Are there many similar errors?
2. Have you checked that the like operation caused the error?
3. Idea of Devart seems probable. Mixing of different encoding can be source of weird bugs. It can fail only for some values. What is a field type of item? You can use convert ([mysql help](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html)).
4. Possibly you can replace like with call of locate or instr function.